# Distance between exponential increase values don't add up

Tags: javascript, math, exponential

My task is to take two values within a range and figure out the distance between them as a percentage. The catch is that the range should also apply an exponential curve.

With numbers ranging from 1 to 100, the distance between 1 & 3 should be 2 without an exponential curve. With a curve multiplier of 0.5, that number should greatly decrease as the distance between the values is small at the beginning and larger at the end.

The problem is that this calculation is just not working in javascript. In the example below, the exponential calculation is applied, but the difference between 1 & 3 is 4.196, already too large. The difference between 97 & 99 is 29.698 which should be much bigger.

```
const getPercentage = (value, max) => 100 / max * value;

const calculateTrajectory = (value, trajectory) => value * Math.pow(value, trajectory);

const getDistance = (value1, value2, max, min, trajectory) => {
    const baseMax = max - min;
        const value = [getPercentage(value1 - min, baseMax),    getPercentage(value2 - min, baseMax)];

    value.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    value[0] = calculateTrajectory(value[0], trajectory);
    value[1] = calculateTrajectory(value[1], trajectory);
    return value[1] - value[0];
}

const addDistance = (distance, id) => {
    document.body.innerHTML += `${id}: ${distance}<br />`;
}

addDistance(getDistance(1, 3, 100, 0, 0.5), 'A'); // 4.196152422706632
addDistance(getDistance(97, 99, 100, 0, 0.5), 'B'); // 29.698355961331572
addDistance(getDistance(1, 3, 100, 0, 0), 'C'); // 2
```

You can see this example live here: https://jsfiddle.net/zeqp1gs3/3/

Here is an example of an exponential curve but I cannot recreate this calculation on my jsfiddle example: https://codepen.io/krazyjakee/pen/brEKpW

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, but note that `value * Math.pow(value, trajectory)` is effectively `Math.pow(value, trajectory + 1)`

Comment: What should the result be for your examples if you work them out on paper? Could you post that along with the calculations you did?

Comment: why are you multiplying by value calculateTrajectory and not just returning the exponent?

Comment: Be more clear on what you mean with `curve multiplier` and what your actual output should be. Also, formula for should be written as `value/max * 100`

Comment: I made it a bunch clearer already, [check it out](https://jsfiddle.net/wagenaartje/zeqp1gs3/4/). You do also understand that `0.5` is not a multiplier but the square root?

Comment: Thank you all. Please see [this graph](https://codepen.io/krazyjakee/pen/brEKpW). It shows an exponential curve with a small text field you can change the number to change the curve. I cannot recreate this functionality or numbers in @ThomasW 's [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/wagenaartje/zeqp1gs3/4/). Is anyone else able to see what I am missing here?